# In a python list of single-key multiple-value dictionaries how can I modify the nth value of each dictionary?

Tags: python

In a large file the following being part of it, I need to add 1 in a loop to the second value (now set to 0) of certain keys, but I have not been able to find a way to do it:

```
[{'TCGA-KL-8331-01A-11D-2310-10': ('T>G ATG', 0)},
{'TCGA-KL-8331-01A-11D-2310-10': ('T>C CTA', 0)}, 
{'TCGA-KL-8343-01A-11D-2310-10': ('T>G TTG', 0)},
{'TCGA-KL-8343-01A-11D-2310-10': ('T>G GTC', 0)}, 
{'TCGA-KO-8417-01A-11D-2310-10': ('T>G TTA', 0)}, 
{'TCGA-KO-8417-01A-11D-2310-10': ('C>G GCA', 0)}]
```

If each dictionary is d, the code `d.values()[1]+=1` gives the error `'dict_values' object does not support indexing` and by `list(d.values())[0][1]+=1` I get `'tuple' object does not support item assignment`. Is there a way forward?

**edit**

Input file is tsv and this list is generated earlier in the script. I write, for example:

```
for m in linesList:
  for n in patMutsList:
    if m.keys()==n.keys() and list(m.values())[0][2]==list(n.values())[0][0]:
      list(n.values())[0][1]+=1
```

Comment: Do all of your dictionaries have a single entry, as in the example?

Comment: What does the file look like and how are you loading it?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Not quite sure how you mean, but what I want to do is whenever a condition is true, add 1 to zero. I can't get this value modifiable.

Comment: @user200783: No, the keys are different.

Comment: @Jab: Input file is tsv and this list is generated earlier in the script. I write, for example:
for m in linesList:
    for n in patMutsList:
        if m.keys()==n.keys() and list(m.values())[0][2]==list(n.values())[0][0]:
            list(n.values())[0][1]+=1
which does not work. This is while the if phrase works perfectly by printing yes/no instead.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54825935/edit) your question so this is easier to read. Next time, it's easier to do this then reply that you "edited" your question

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function like this:

```
def increment_value(aDict):
    item = next(iter(aDict.items()))
    k,v = item
    d,n = v
    aDict[k] = d,n + 1
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
values = [ {'TCGA   ...'  # rest of list of dicts elided
increment_value(values[2])
print(value[2])
```

Output:

```
{'TCGA-KL-8343-01A-11D-2310-10': ('T>G TTG', 1)}
```

**Update:**

From your edit it seems that you are looping through `values` above (You call them `patMutsList`) and `n` is the current item, so the instead of:

```
list(n.values())[0][1]+=1
```

You can call:

```
increment_value(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I like @quamrana's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54826170/225020) as it works for your data as is.

If possible you should try to load the data as a `dict` and move from `tuples` to `lists` as tuples are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) This is just going off the information provided. Assuming each `dict` has one key like your example shown.

So your data would look like this:

```
data = {
    'TCGA-KL-8331-01A-11D-2310-10': ['T>G ATG', 0],
    'TCGA-KL-8331-01A-11D-2310-10': ['T>C CTA', 0], 
    'TCGA-KL-8343-01A-11D-2310-10': ['T>G TTG', 0],
    'TCGA-KL-8343-01A-11D-2310-10': ['T>G GTC', 0], 
    'TCGA-KO-8417-01A-11D-2310-10': ['T>G TTA', 0], 
    'TCGA-KO-8417-01A-11D-2310-10': ['C>G GCA', 0]
}
```

This way you could change a value much easier using the following syntax:

```
key = 'TCGA-KL-8331-01A-11D-2310-10'
data[key][1] += 1

print(data[key])
#['T>G ATG', 1]
```

**edit**

If it isn't a troublesome rework, consider loading your data as a dict.

Consider taking a peek at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752209/python-script-tsv-conversion-to-json) question.

Or if this is something better done after the data is loaded, using the following or a variation thereof:

```
def unpack_data(data):
    unpacked = dict(_ for d in data for _ in d.items())
    return({k: list(v) for k, v in unpacked.items()})
```

Comment: Your values are still `tuples`. Did you mean to convert them to lists?

Comment: Yes, silly me using copy paste.. *facepalm*.. edited

Comment: So perhaps you could show some code which would convert from the structure that the OP shows to the `data` that you have.

Comment: Give me a minute will add this in. Although that was why I was asking how OP was loading said data.

Comment: Some of the keys are the same and it is therefore not possible to load the data as a dictioary.

Comment: @ardalana: Are you sure? You said they were different 35 minutes ago.

Comment: Again, I don't know how exactly you're loading your data, but I edited my question to show how you might unpack your data

Comment: @quamrana: you can look more carefully for yourself and see that they are some different and some the same. So, not all the same, not all different, which is why we need to have a list of dictionaries!

Comment: So use a dict of dicts then, change my last line to `dict` where it says `list` Nothing else should change